# Window.clipboardData.getData('Text') not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, clipboard

As we are facing issue, when reading clipboard data in chrome browser. When user click a menu in the application, we need to paste the copied data in a textbox.

Also when user presses a shortcut like <kbd>F9</kbd>, we need to do the same. As chrome have restriction in reading clipboard data, we can read data from clipboard only in paste events. In my case I don't have paste event and also can't manually trigger the paste event in Chrome.

`window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` in IE and
`event.clipboardData.getData('Text')` in Chrome when the event is paste.

Please suggest some solutions for reading the clipboard data without events in Chrome.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? I need to do something similar

Comment: Any solution? I need too.

Comment: Not yet got anything